# mysql rephasing three counts into one query

Tags: mysql

I currently have three queries which I would like to make into one. here are the three.

```
$sql = "SELECT Email FROM table GROUP BY Email having (sum(payment = 'paid')) = 0";
$sql = "SELECT count(DISTINCT Email) from table WHERE payment='paid'"; 
$sql = "SELECT count(DISTINCT Email) from table";
```

the first query would be to find users who have not paid before, the second where they have at least paid once, and the third is a count of all emails in the database.

Is it possible to fit them all into one? Thanks

EDIT
The end result should give me a table like this

```
TotalDistinctUsers   NonpayingUsers   PayingUsers
     3                2                1
```

Current table structure

```
id   email           payment   item
1    abc@123.com      paid     newspaper
2    def@123.com      unpaid   magazine
3    ghi@123.com      unpaid   books
4    abc@123.com      unpaid   books
```

Comment: `having (sum(payment = 'paid')) = 0`  I dont understand this part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hack involved but i think it can solve your problem. Try it once, if it works, I will explain you what I have done:

```
    Select NonPayingusers, PayingUsers, TotalDistinctUsers FROM 

    (SELECT count(Distinct Email) as NonpayingUsers, 0 as id   FROM table GROUP BY Email 
having (sum(payment = 'paid')) = 0)t1

    left join(

    SELECT count(DISTINCT Email) as PayingUsers, 0 as id from table WHERE payment='paid'
    )t2 on t1.id =t2.id 

    left join(

    SELECT count(DISTINCT Email) as TotalDistinctUsers, 0 as id from table
    )t3 on t2.id =t3.id
```

Here "t1, t2 and t3" are temporary tables with a dummy column "id" added to each table so that they can be joined on that column.